# Fluid dynamic image centered in div - resize with div immediately

Tags: css, image, resize, centering, fluid-layout

So, I have a fully fluid web page.
There is a parent DIV with width:100%, and inside an IMAGE with style:

```
<div>
     <img src="image.png" alt="" />
</div>

<style>
    div{ width:100% }
    img{
      display: block;
      margin: auto;
      max-width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

Image is centered in div. I do not know the size of image, but it is always smaller than parent DIV, so there is white space from img borders to div borders. Now, when you resize the browser, the image is not resizing until the parent DIV reaches the borders of the image.

If image would have style width:100%, then it would stretch beyond real size...

I would like this image to scale with div immediately when browser window is resized.
If image canvas would be 100% of parent div, the behaviour would be like I wanted (the image would resize immediately because image would be 100% od div's width). But I can not make images to be like that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with pure CSS, but you can use some jQuery - http://jsfiddle.net/UcV7y/

```
var ratio = $("img").parent().width() / $("img").width();

$(window).resize(function() {
    $("img").width( $("img").parent().width() / ratio + "px" );
});
​
```

Comment: Very clever solution. I think it will fit just fine in my project :)

Comment: Hello Zolthan, I have same issue but there is some more functioning needed for image there is in fiddle space in -left- and -right- appears that no needed. Any solution for the same, if image crop needed then from center for variation resolution, i have no idea how it can possible using css/js (in short fill parent div with scaling image).. thank you

Comment: @BharatBhatiya can you please clarify the issue you're having? or create a fiddle and describe what's exactly wrong and what's the desired result?

Comment: Thanks for replay
please check in fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lnn7vmap/
I have require image fit in div and from center of image, i have trying some code but not getting proper solution.

Comment: @BharatBhatiya http://jsbin.com/debaceguxe/edit?html,css,js,output  this?

Comment: @BharatBhatiya It doesn't really matter. Now you have the idea how it should work - you just calculate the width of parent and child, and absolutely potion the child inside its' parent. If you need it resizable - just put it into a `.resize()`